# How convert class component to functional with function constructor?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert this class component to a function component but I need the component to have these static properties.

```
export class InputBox<T extends string|number|undefined = undefined> extends React.Component<IInputBoxProps<T>, IInputBoxState> {
    static displayName = "InputBox";
    static defaultProps: IInputBoxProps<string|number> = {
        disabled: false,
        rightAligned: false,
        id: "",
        keySelectIndex: 0,
    }

... rest of component
}
```

I have tried this code:

```
export const InputBox: React.FunctionComponent<IInputBoxProps<any>> = <T extends string | number | undefined = undefined >(props: IInputBoxProps<T>) => {
    InputBox.displayName = "InputBox";
    InputBox.defaultProps = {
        disabled: false,
        rightAligned: false,
        id: "",
        keySelectIndex: 0,
    }

... rest of component
}
```

When I run this code I get a eslint error saying that:

`FunctionComponent<IInputBox<any>>' is not a constructor function type.`

`T = any` does not work here either. I know `any` kinda makes typescript useless but I can't seem to get around the error.

How can I type a function component with a "constructor function type" and what does that mean exactly?

What is the difference between a function constructor and class constructor in a class constructor?
Should I type static props differently in a function component?

Comment: Something like? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOASToDswBXGAIQgA8AFHMAM4AeACoA+OAF44Ab1JwFcACbABKAEYAbJEoBccdRAjaUjADTzFUYAHMAFjACCm24x37Dx1OcsLgeuBELRTgAayRKAGUkbQwmJSQufUYWEHUkKAsAX3I0CEYBeCZWDm4pOFE4RJgkRiUBOELrRhs4AB84FLSM9rgWOqRMYDclcv6EoZGxAAowfgF9BmY2Tl550TEASikJORCAen24ADpTuCJCuAhMODzwfNqYX3OkGBYoRk6WTU0AblIcqRiituMcVAIwJoUJQAHIoEC0aQAImBpS4SP+qNWYMGKG+MD4EEE5T2inBGm0AUwKE0AiQwSstgczlc7jg1Np9Oe-n0SKRDIU4SiMSQcQGSTgAAZsrl8pdMEZykIsWV9mIgA

Comment: I still get lint error. Also I don't get `defaultProps` or `displayName` as a intellisense suggestion?

Comment: @Kulio what version of TS are you using? Aleksey's example gives me intellisense suggestions in 4.4.4

Comment: `"typescript": "^4.4.4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Generic Component

```
export const InputBox: React.FunctionComponent<IInputBoxProps<any>> = <T ...
```

This sort of syntax will never work properly because you are trying to set the generic `T` *on the function itself*.  The point of the generic is that the `T` can be different every time the function is called.

So you cannot use the `React.FunctionComponent` type here.  But you don't need to -- just set the types of the props.

If your eslint settings uses the rule `explicit-module-boundary-names` then you will also need to set the return type as `JSX.Element` (or `JSX.Element | null` if it might return `null`).

---

#### Default Props

`defaultProps` doesn't really exist on function components ([See discussion here](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/16210)).  Rather than trying to set the `defaultProps` property on your function component, think about what that property is actually doing and how you can implement that functionality.

I would handle this by using the values from your `defaultProps` as the defaults when destucturing the properties. (Note: I'm not sure what the `T` here applies to).

```
const InputBox = <T extends string | number | undefined = undefined>(
    props: IInputBoxProps<T>
) => {
    const {
        disabled = false,
        rightAligned = false,
        id = "",
        keySelectIndex = 0,
        // ... other props without defaults
    } = props;
...
```

or inline

```
const InputBox = <T extends string | number | undefined = undefined>(
    { disabled = false, rightAligned = false, id = "", keySelectIndex = 0, data }: IInputBoxProps<T>
) => {
...
```

---

#### Display Name

The `displayName` is not really needed because the inferred display name will be the name of the function.  It will already be `"InputBox"`.  You should only be getting eslint errors here if you have used the [option](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/display-name.md#ignoretranspilername-default-false) `{ ignoreTranspilerName: true }`.

As you can see in the [rule examples](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/display-name.md), you must first create the function and then assign the `displayName` property to the function.  Aleksey's comment does this correctly.

```
const InputBox = <T extends string | number | undefined = undefined>(
    props: IInputBoxProps<T>
): JSX.Element => {
    /* ... */
}
InputBox.displayName = "InputBox";
```

Comment: Ah ok I understand. Thanks for this very detailed answer. Appreciate it!